# Cannot refresh token in laravel JWT

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

I have this middleware in laravel

> JwtMiddleWare:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
      /**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */

try {
    $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    if ($e instanceof \Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException){
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Token is Invalid'],401);
    }else if ($e instanceof \Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException){
        try
        {
          $refreshed = JWTAuth::refresh(JWTAuth::getToken());
          $user = JWTAuth::setToken($refreshed)->toUser();
          $request->headers->set('Authorization','Bearer '.$refreshed);
        }catch (JWTException $e){
            return response()->json([
                'code'   => 103,
                'message' => 'Token cannot be refreshed, please Login again'
            ]);
        }
    }else{
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Authorization Token not found'],401);
    }
}
return $next($request);
}
```

sometimes when there is issue with token i get these two errors :

> Error 1: message: "The token has been blacklisted",
>
> Error 2: Token has expired and can no longer be refreshed

In my try block  `$refreshed = JWTAuth::refresh(JWTAuth::getToken());` i'm getting this error `The token has been blacklisted` in my frontend code i'm already catching exception if there is 401 error.

What is want is if there is any type of error the user should be redirected to login page.

> Auth Interceptors :

```
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private tokenService: TokenService,private _router: Router,private auth: AuthStateService, private toastr: ToastrService) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
        const accessToken = this.tokenService.getToken();
        req = req.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
            }
        });
        //return next.handle(req);

        return next.handle(req).pipe(
            catchError(
              (err, caught) => {
                if (err.status === 401){
                  this.handleAuthError();
                  return of(err);
                }
                throw err;
              }
            )
          );
    }
    private handleAuthError() { 
        this.toastr.error('Warning', 'Unauthorised Access');
        this.auth.setAuthState(false);
        this.tokenService.removeToken();
        this._router.navigate(['/login'])
      }
    
}
```

Any solution please. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for Error 1**

Add this to your `.env`.

```
JWT_BLACKLIST_ENABLED=false
```

It will remove the error, but this is not a proper solution because it would expose a vulnerability, so you must maintain the security of a blacklist by setting the `blacklist grace period` to `30` for 30 seconds.

```
JWT_BLACKLIST_GRACE_PERIOD=30
```

It will eliminate the issue of tokens dying.

Please keep in mind that you can change configuration options in your code during runtime. I used this code, and it worked for me:

```
config([
    'jwt.blacklist_enabled' => true
]);
auth()->logout();
JWTAuth::invalidate(JWTAuth::parseToken());
```

**Solution for Error 2**

I had the same issue, and after trying everything I could find on the internet, nothing seemed to work. So I studied the config/jwt.php file on my own and solved the problem by modifying the following line:

```
'refresh_ttl' => env ('JWT_REFRESH_TTL', 20160),
'ttl' => env ('JWT_TTL', 60),
```

By

```
'refresh_ttl' => env ('JWT_REFRESH_TTL', Null),
'ttl' => env ('JWT_TTL', NULL),
```

**Another solution:**

So the refresh route is secure, but it doesn't pass through the auth middleware when the token expires, so I added the refresh route as follows:

```
$this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login', 'refresh']]);
```